# How to handle data binding on a dynamic set of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create an angular directive making me able to select from a list of items group by category. Each item should be selectable using a checkbox.

The input data to the directive is something like

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "category1",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "item1"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "item2"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "item3"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "item4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "category2",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "item5"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "item6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the object of pre-checked items is:

```
{
  "1": [
    "2",
    "4"
  ]
}
```

Here item with id 2 and 4 from category with 1 should be pre-checked.

My code results in this view:

[image: select box]

The checked-state is handled using the `ng-checked` directive:

```
<input id="item-{{item.id}}" value="{{item.id}}" type="checkbox" ng-checked="isSelected(cat,item)">
```

When checking/unchecking an item, the selected items object should be updated to reflect the current state. How can I handle this? Should all this be structured in a different way?

See my plumber: http://plnkr.co/edit/6fbfZnQCq5fq1zDp8VIB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, there is multiple ways to achieve this. My suggestion:

Use `ng-model` on your inputs:

```
<input ng-model="selected[cat.id][item.id]" 
       id="item-{{item.id}}" 
       value="{{item.id}}" 
       type="checkbox" 
       ng-checked="selected[cat.id][item.id]">
```

This will require a slight modification of your `selectedItems` property (it is now an object instead of an array):

```
$scope.selectedItems = {
    "1": {
        "2": true,
        "4": true
    }
};
```

The `ng-checked` in the HTML will automatically check the items which are marked `true`.

I'm not sure how you want to handle the selection of categories, but I hope this will give you an idea!

Check the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0jK8szS5xN5llT9lWKiq?p=preview).